# Access & Select specific sub-list elements  with a Pure Function

Tags: list, function, wolfram-mathematica

- **Part I : ACCESS**

*Provided with :*

```
list = {{z, x, c, d}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}
```

*I would like to do the following :*

```
(#3/2 + #1/3) &[list[[1]]]
```

*Which sadly result in  :*

[image]

*While my desired output would be :*

[image]

*obtained with :*

```
 (#3/2 + #1/3) &[z, x, c, d]
```

- **Part II : CONDITIONAL SELECTION**

Trying to do this :

```
Select[list[[2]], # > 2 &]
```

How could I specify the sublist with # if possible ?

**Answer**, courtesy of **Leonid** (detailed in a comment below) :

```
Select[#[[2]], # > 2 &] &[list]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
(#[[3]]/2 + #[[1]]/3) &[list[[1]]]
```

#1 is the first argument of a function and #3 is the third. You only provide
one argument, namely list[[1]]. Since list[[1]] is a list it is mapped 
over your function. 
 #[[1]] and #[[3]] specify the first and third part/element of the first argument.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Sequence`: `(#3/2 + #1/3) &[Sequence @@ (list[[1]])]` does what you want. `Sequence` can be very useful

Comment: @500, @acl Could also use `Apply`: `(#3/2 + #1/3) &@@list[[1]]`.

Comment: @acl, @Leonid, Thank You. Is the question title better worded now  ?

Comment: @500 I'd call it "Pure function to access specific sub-list elements in a nested list" or something like that.

Comment: @Leonid : Trying to apply that on Select :

Trying to do this :
Select[list[[2]], # > 2 &]

How could I specify the sublist with # if possible  ?
Select[list, #[[2]] > 2 &] does not work.

Comment: @500 Typically this would be another question that is better to ask separately. Here it is sufficiently linked to the first one, so I suggest to edit your question and make part 1 (access) and part 2 (select). The title could be "Access and select ...". One possible answer is `Select[#[[2]], # > 2 &] &[list]`. Note that this is a little more involved construct containing nested pure functions. I suggest that you add this (or some other) solution after your second question in your edit, so that future readers could see it.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you may find useful to use some notation to improve readability. For example, elaborating on Markus' answer:

```
list = {{z, x, c, d}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}
third[x_List] := x[[3]];

third@#/2 + First@#/3 &@ First@list
(*
-> c/2+z/3
*)
```

Answer (score 3):

For the first, you just need `Apply` (short form `@@`):

```
#3/2 + #1/3 & @@ list[[1]]
```

Comment: I mentioned this one in the comment to the answer by @acl

Comment: @Leonid well that's just plain strange:  after reading "Answer, courtesy of Leonid (detailed in a comment below)" I looked for comments below, and I didn't see any, which I found confusing!  I suppose it could have been a glitch.  Nevertheless, I think this method is worthy of its own answer.  +1 on your comment, and one closer to the silver Pundit badge for you.

Comment: "I think this method is worthy of its own answer" - I do not disagree, so +1.